# Start from a different element when operating on a list in prolog

Tags: list, prolog

In prolog is it possible to start from an nth element rather than the first in a list.

I have a function

```
checker([Ms,Fs|Ps] ) :-  %%start from the beginning of the list when size is 2+
```

Which gets a list of n lists like so `[[one, two], [three], [four, five]]` is it possible to start operating from `[three]` rather than the beginning? Effectively skipping the first element of the list always?

I have tried things like

```
checker([[],Ms,Fs|Ps] ) :- %% + a few others like this - no luck
```

Basically, I want to disregard the first element of the list when i start operating

Cheers

Comment: You probably meant `checker([[Ms,Fs]|Ps] ) :- ` instead...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

I added a

```
check([]).
check([H|T]) :-
checker(T).
```

Worked a charm, now I just call Check instead.

Comment: `Check` needs to start with a lower case letter to be valid.